# Ruby On Rails: Making a Home Page with Administrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-administrate, administrate

I'm using the Administrate gem to set up my Admin page. I have successfully done so and generated this Admin Page:

[Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEo0H.png)

Now I want to create a Home Page that my login page will redirect to after users successfully logged in. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use gem Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise for authentication.

> Devise will create some helpers to use inside your controllers and views. To set up a controller with user authentication, just add this before_action (assuming your devise model is 'User'):

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```